# HTTP Compression with ASP.Net MVC on IIS 6.0

Tags: iis, iis-6

I'm serving some farily large webpages (~600k) via MVC over IIS 6.0. Is there any opportunity to use HTTP compression to reduce the amount of bandwidth used?

Is this possible without a file extension to identify to IIS that it should compress the MVC response?

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: a full article http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2004/01/12/57916.aspx

Comment: I saw that, but unless I'm missing the boat, we need to specify file extensions "First thing to do is add aspx,  asmx, php and any other extension that you need to the list extensions in HcScriptFileExtensions." Since there are no extensions for MVC, is there any opporunity to use compression?

Comment: you're true, see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enable wildcard mapping, IIS 6 compression no longer works for extensionless URL (like MVC) because IIS 6 does not see any extension which is defined in IIS Metabase.

One solution is to use a custom HttpModule to do the compression for dynamic requests by yourself. There is no magic in Gzip : it's simply GzipStream.

there is an example [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2008/06/30/deploy-asp-net-mvc-on-iis-6-solve-404-compression-and-performance-problems.aspx) and sample code [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/fastmvc).